# Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

im trying to redirect a user to a specific route if hes not logged in and unauthorized to update a User (401) and got got this "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined" whereas is did work just fine for displaying Contacts. But for updating the user it doesn.
This is a creator of Action function in the Action folder Index.js file.
Also want to mention that the new user gets updated in the db just fine.
thank you

```
export const updateUser = user => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response = axios.patch(`${backend_URL}/users/me/edit`, user);
      const newUser = {
        ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")),
        ...response.data.req.user
      };
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(newUser));
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_USER", payload: response.data.req.user });
      history.push("/users/me");
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 401) {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_ALERT",
          payload: { msg: err.response.data.error, type: "danger" }
        });
        history.push("/users/login");
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_ALERT",
          payload: { msg: err.response.data.error, type: "danger" }
        });
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: As an aside, does `axios.patch` return a promise? Seems like you're missing an `await` there.

Comment: you are right. i forgot it, so i just fixed it and it does save the new User in the localStore, but i still get the "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

Comment: Probably missing await at axios.patch

Comment: Sooo the problem was the "await" thing and "response.data" not response.data.req.user .. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

axios.patch return promise. So need to handle this. You can use await axios.patch for handle promise.

Comment: yeah i just added it, and it saves the new used to the localStore but there is still status Undefined

Answer (score 0):

The object err does not have a property called response. Instead you should use valid properties like *name* or *message*:

I don't thing you can get the error status, so get it by name.

```
export const updateUser = user => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response = axios.patch(`${backend_URL}/users/me/edit`, user);
      const newUser = {
        ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")),
        ...response.data.req.user
      };
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(newUser));
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_USER", payload: response.data.req.user });
      history.push("/users/me");
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.name === "ReferenceError") {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_ALERT",
          payload: { msg: err.message, type: "danger" }
        });
        history.push("/users/login");
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_ALERT",
          payload: { msg: err.message, type: "danger" }
        });
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Look at the documentation about  errors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: Thank you Alex, actually the problem was "await" and "response.data.req.user" i removed req.user and with "response.data" everything worked just fine :)